# Android Wear - Sensors Usage

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm  programming with Android Wear 2.0 on Huawei Watch 2.0 and I'm using different sensors. When I display the list of sensors via `SensorsManager.getSensorsList()`, I've seen a lot of sensors and I can't find any documentation on some of them. I suppose they are software based.

Does anybody know the usage of the following sensors? :

```
name: huawei Activity Reminder Sensor
Stringtype: com.huawei.watch.activityreminder
Type: 65540

name: huawei motion health
StringType: com.huawei.watch.motionhealth
Type:65538

name: huawei Wear State Sensor
StringType: com.huawei.watch.wearstate
Type: 65542

name: huawei workout Sensor
StringType: com.huawei.bone
Type: 65544
```

Comment: You might get a better answer at [android.se]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check this.